# Como obtener los extras de una notificacion de firebase (cloud messaging) en android?

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Tengo una aplicación que recibe notificaciones desde Firebase usando Cloud Messaging, tengo una clase donde sobreescribo el método:

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {}
```

Pero este método solo funciona cuando la app está en primer plano, en algunos ejemplos encontré que se puede recibir en los extras:

```
 if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        Log.i("entrea","entra");
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Pero `getIntent().getExtras()` siempre es null

la notificación la mano con una url que necesito abrir en la app:

[image: datos de la notificacion]

Comment: Pero, ¿qué es lo que quieres en sí, mostrar la notificación en la UI cuando ésta ocurra?

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que quiero es obtener los datos extras que envio en la notificacion

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente `remoteMessage` lo conviertes a `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> data = message.getData();
```

y posteriormente la información la obtienes de acuerdo a su llave que definiste en el mensaje enviado, por ejemplo:

```
  String titulo = data.get("titulo");
  String url = data.get("url");
```

**La app debe recibir en primer y segundo plano las notificaciones, esto se realiza en la clase que extiende de `FirebaseMessagingService` en su método `onMessageReceived()`** :

```
public class Mensajes extends FirebaseMessagingService {

   @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {

    ...
    ...

    }

}
```

obviamente esta clase debe estar registrada en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` como servicio:

```
<service android:name=".Mensajes">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: pero el onMessageReceived veo que solo se ejecuta cuando la app esta abierta, cuando la app esta en segundo plano no se ejecuta

Comment: onMessageReceived() debe llamarse cuando recibes una notificación cuando la app esta en background o en primer plano https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive  el problema que mencionas debe a que probablemente tu app tiene una restricción debido a otros procesos que pudiera estar realizando tu app https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization#bg-restrict